# What is the matter with my router?

Tags: ip

The WAN IP displayed on my router is 100.65.58.175 ,it is a reserved ip.

```
curl ipinfo.com
"ip": "111.29.133.133"
```

What is the matter with my router?

[image]

Comment: Nothing. Your router goes to another router.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with Unix or Linux.

Comment: There is only one router in my home net ,does that mean someone hack me?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, as was said.  There is nothing wrong with your router.  This is simply *carrier-grade NAT* in action.  The WAN side of your router is assigned an IP address from 100.64.0.0/10, and the actual IP address seen by Internet at large is the outside IP address of your entire carrier.

## Further reading

- J. Weil, V. Kuarsingh, C. Donley, C. Liljenstolpe (April 2012). *[IANA-Reserved IPv4 Prefix for Shared Address Space](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598)*.  RFC 6598/BCP 153.  ISSN 2070-1721.  Internet Engineering Task Force.